# Skeletal animation of DirectX files in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, animation, directx

I'm trying to import *.x files to my engine and animate them using OpenGL (without shaders for now, but that isn't really relevant right now). I've found the format reference at MSDN, but it doesn't help much in the problem.

So - basically - I've created a file containing a simple animation of a demon-like being with 7 bones (main, 2 for the tail, and 4 for the legs), from which only 2 (the ones in the right leg) are animated at the moment. I've tested the mesh in the DXViewer, and it seems to work perfectly there, so the problem must be the side of my code.

When I export the mesh, I get a file containing lots of information, from which there are 3 important places for the skeletal animation (all the below matrices are for the RLeg2 bone):

1. SkinWeights - matrixOffset

   ```
   -0.361238,  -0.932141, -0.024957,  0.000000,
    0.081428,  -0.004872, -0.996669,  0.000000,
    0.928913,  -0.362066,  0.077663,  0.000000,
    0.139213,  -0.057892, -0.009323,  1.000000
   ```
2. FrameTransformMatrix

   ```
   0.913144,  0.000000, -0.407637,  0.000000,
   0.069999,  0.985146,  0.156804,  0.000000,
   0.401582, -0.171719,  0.899580,  0.000000,
   0.000000, -0.000000,  0.398344,  1.000000
   ```
3. AnimationKey matrix in bind pose

   ```
   0.913144,  0.000000, -0.407637,  0.000000, 
   0.069999,  0.985146,  0.156804,  0.000000,
   0.401582, -0.171719,  0.899580,  0.000000,
   0.000000, -0.000000,  0.398344,  1.000000
   ```

My question is - **what do I exactly do with these matrices?** I've found an equation on the Newcastle University site (http://research.ncl.ac.uk/game/mastersdegree/graphicsforgames/skeletalanimation/), but there's only 1 matrix there. The question is - **how do I combine these matrices to get the vertex transform matrix**?

Comment: What version of OpenGL are you targeting?

Comment: I can't see how that's relevant (I don't think the solution depends on a newer OpenGL version), but I got version 3.3 available on my PC. I also use GLU, GLUT and GLEW in my project. For matrix operations, I use my own class which implements overloaded operators, transposition and an inverse function (all tested on sample matrices, work properly).

Comment: Yeah, I've asked to know if you use shaders or not (Very much OpenGL novices on SO use deprecated stuff, such as matrix stack and immediate mode). But now I see that problem is not an implementation of skinning, but a mesh data itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This post is not pretend to be a full answer, but a set of helpful links.

**How to get all information needed for animation**

The question is how do you import your mesh, and why do you do this. You can fight  with `.x` meshes for a months, but this doesn't make any sense, because `.x` is a very basic, old and really not good enough format. You don't find many fans of `.x` format on StackOverflow. =)

`.x` file stores animation data in a tricky way. It was intended to load via set of `D3DX*()` functions. But, to get bones and weights from it manually, you must preprocess loaded data. Much things to code. Here is a big post, explaining how to:

[Loading and displaying .X files without DirectX](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/directx-and-xna/loading-and-displaying-x-files-without-directx-r2221)

Good way to do things is just switch to some mesh loading library. The most popular and universal one is [Assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/). At least, look at their [docs](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/data.html) and/or source code, on how they handle loading and preprocessing, and what whey have as output. Also, here is a good explanation:

[Tutorial 38 - Skeletal Animation With Assimp](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial38/tutorial38.html)

So, with assimp you can stop fighting and begin animating right now. And maybe later, when you'll find idea on how it's works, you can write your own loader.

**When you've got all information needed for animation**

Skeletal animation is a basic topic that explained in details all around the web.

- You can find basic vertex shader for animation here:
  [OpenGL Wiki: Skeletal Animation](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Skeletal_Animation)
- Here is a explanation of how all works (but implemented in fixed-function style): [Basic Bones System](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:Basic_Bones_System)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, I'll check the links when I can find some time. I'm stuck with the *.x format tho, cuz it's the only format my 3D graphics program can export to, which supports skeletal animation.

I've writen the importer, and it works... except for the animation, which is kinda broken (but still moves!). It would be a waste of my effort to move to a library now, but I'll check their code for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Since **Drop** provided links that talk about the problem, and give clues on how to solve it, but don't quite provide a simple answer, i feel obliged to leave the solution here, in case someone else stumbles on the same problem.

### To get the new vertex position in "bind pose"

```
v'(i) = v(i)*Σ(transform(bone)*W(bone,i))
```

where:
`v'(i)` - new vertex position,
`v(i)` - old vertex position, and
`W(bone,i)` - weight of the transformation.
(and of course Σ is the sum from 0 to the amount of bones in the skeleton)

The `transform(bone)` is equal to `sw(bone) * cM(bone)`, where `sw` is the matrix found inside the **SkinWeights** tag, and `cM(bone)` is calculated using a recursive function:

```
cM(bone)
{
  if(bone->parent)
    return localTransform*cM(bone->parent);
  else
    return localTransform;
}
```

The `localTransform` is the matrix located inside the **FrameTransformMatrix** tag.

### To get the new vertex position in a certain animation frame

Do the exact same operation as mentioned above, but instead of the matrix in **FrameTransformMatrix**, use one of the matrices inside the appropriate **AnimationKey** tag. Note that when an animation is playing, the matrix inside the **FrameTransformMatrix** tag becomes **unused**. Which means, you'll probably end up ignoring it most of the time.